# Multi-tier namespace specification in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces, coding-style

A client of mine has coding standards that call for namespaces need to be defined with all individual names and braces on separate lines. This leads to the vertical-space-consuming (a point which is annoying some developers on the team):

```
namespace MyCompany
{
    namespace MyProduct
    {
        namespace ThisFunctionalUnit
        {
            :
        }
    }
}
```

Given that the vast majority of their code consists of files totally wrapped in the sort of hierarchy seen above, they could minimise the problem by allowing:

```
namespace MyCompany { namespace MyProduct { namespace ThisFunctionalUnit
{
    :
}}} // namespace MyCompany::MyProduct::ThisFunctionalUnit
```

That comes with other issues but is workable. However, it seems to me the whole issue would go away if C++ allowed multi-tier specification of namespaces in the first place, along the lines of:

```
namespace MyCompany::MyProduct::ThisFunctionalUnit
{
    :
}
```

My question is really, why *doesn't* C++ allow this? It can't be because `::` can be used within namespace levels since that would render `using namespace` unworkable.

Does anyone know why this is the case, or whether it's likely to be redressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested namespace definitions are allowed now, in C++17:

```
namespace A::B::C {
```

It's equivalent to:

```
namespace A { namespace B { namespace C {
```